# Scroll to the Bottom of the Page after postBack

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to Scroll Automatically to the Bottom of the Page when I click on the button. I have found lot of solutions on the forum but it don't work for me. I tried this in Java Script :

```
<asp:Button  ID="btn_add_action1" runat="server" Text="Ajouter une action" onclick="btn_add_action1_Click" OnClientClick = "goToBottom()" />
```

With the JS function :

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

or

```
document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
```

I found this here : [Scroll Automatically to the Bottom of the Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page)

I tried many other solution but it don't work

Comment: do you really need a asp button? try normal html button. now page will postback while click on this button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onClick go to the bottom of page using jQuery .animate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188584/onclick-go-to-the-bottom-of-page-using-jquery-animate)

Comment: I realy need a asp button because it is associated with this function btn_add_action1_Click who execute an sql query...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you click the button, a PostBack is performed. That means the scrolling position will be lost. If you want to scroll to the bottom of the page you have to do it after the PostBack is done, by using `ScriptManager`

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your button code

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "scrollDown", "setTimeout(function () { window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight); }, 25);", true);
}
```

There is also something called `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack`, that does something similar, it goes to the same position as the button click after PostBack.

Comment: IT WORK ! Thank you so much, it was exacltly what I needed and I understand the problem with the PostBack it's logic...

Answer (score 2):

Kindly Put **MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"**  on your Page header <%@ Page %>, it will automatically scroll where you was last time.